# Prove that the given sequence contains all natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is defined in the following manner. Let $a_1$ be any arbitrary natural number. Let $S_n=a_1+a_2+…a_n$. Define $a_{n+1}$ to be the smallest natural number $k$ such that $\gcd(S_n,k)=1$ and $a_i \neq k$ for $i=1,2,…,n$. Prove that every natural number appears in this sequence.

My work so far has just been some casework showing that $2$, $3$ and $4$ will always be in the sequence. Not sure how to extend this to all numbers- I tried induction, but that didn't work. Let the induction hypothesis be: at some point all numbers up to $n-1$ have appeared. Then if $n$ is prime then it's quite easy to show that at some point, $S$ will be divisible by $n$ and we are done. But it's not that simple when $n$ has more than one prime divisor.

Comment: Can you list the first few $a_i$ terms?

Comment: @CalvinLin How would that work? $a_1$ is arbitrary so you would have to list infinitely many sequences. Are you suggesting to choose a random value for $a_1$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread. I thought that $a_1 = 1$. Let me revisit this.

Comment: I am doing some rubber-and-pencil thinking, and if I was to gamble some coins on it, my induction hypotesis would be related to the number of prime factors of the number. Yes, your induction would still be from 1 to N-1 to N, but the useful thing is in the prime factorization of N. After all, MCD (N,s) can only be a divisor of N, and the really challenging values are the primes.

Comment: Isn't it the case that for any choice of $a_1>1 \Rightarrow S_1=a_1$, you must have $a_2=1$? $a_2=1$ would be the smallest natural  number not already in the list for which $\gcd (S_1,a_2) = 1$. Then the problem naively appears to be not terribly different from $a_1=1$

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete solution.

---

For $a_1 = 1$.

**Hint:** List out the first 20 terms.

Find a pattern. The pattern doesn't start immediately, which is why I asked for 20 terms.
That should be enough for you to guess what $a_i$ is, then prove it.

---

Here's my guess of how the general case will proceed:

- Show that for any $a_1$, there exists an $N=4k+1$ such that the first $N$ terms in the sequence are the first $N$ integers.
- Then, the result follows from $a_1 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Define $b_n$ as the smallest $m \not\in \{a_j : j \le n\}$. If $\text{gcd}(S_n, b_n)$ equals 1, then $a_{n+1} = b_n$. Assume now that it does not equal 1, so that then $a_{n+1} > b_n$, and therefor $b_{n+1} = b_n$. We have
$$\text{gcd}(S_n, S_{n+1}) = \text{gcd}(S_n, S_n + a_{n+1}) = \text{gcd}(S_n, a_{n+1}) = 1$$
Therefore, $\text{gcd}(S_{n+1}, b_n) = 1$. Now $a_{n+2} = b_{n+1} = b_n$, so that $b_n + 1 \le b_{n+2}$. This last inequality becomes (by an induction argument) $b_{r(n)} + \lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor \le b_{n+2}$, where $r(n)$ equals $1$ if $n$ is odd, and $2$ if it is even. We conclude then that if $k < b_{r(n)} + \lfloor{(n+1)/2}\rfloor$ then $k \in \{a_j : j \le n + 2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**NOT AN ANSWER**

Here for everyone to see is the first 100 elements of this sequence, with $a_1=1$ (generated with Python)

```
[  1.   2.   4.   3.   7.   5.   9.   6.   8.  11.  13.  10.  12.  15.
  17.  14.  16.  19.  21.  18.  20.  23.  25.  22.  24.  27.  29.  26.
  28.  31.  33.  30.  32.  35.  37.  34.  36.  39.  41.  38.  40.  43.
  45.  42.  44.  47.  49.  46.  48.  51.  53.  50.  52.  55.  57.  54.
  56.  59.  61.  58.  60.  63.  65.  62.  64.  67.  69.  66.  68.  71.
  73.  70.  72.  75.  77.  74.  76.  79.  81.  78.  80.  83.  85.  82.
  84.  87.  89.  86.  88.  91.  93.  90.  92.  95.  97.  94.  96.  99.
 101.  98.]
```

If you want to generate lists of your own, here is the code to do so:

```
import numpy as np
N=100
a=np.zeros(N)
a[0]=3
for n in range(1,N):
    S=np.sum(a[:n])
    k_found=False
    k=2
    while k_found==False:
        in_a=True
        while in_a==True:
            if k in a:
                k+=1
            else:
                in_a=False
        if np.gcd(int(S),int(k))==1:
            a[n]=k
            k_found=True
        else:
            k+=1
print(a)
```

Here `a[0]` is the starting element (I have used $0$ because of the way Python indexes lists) and `N` is the number of terms you wish to compute.